# algebraic proof of superiority of OLS over the direct sum of the smaller size OLS

Tags: linear-algebra

Imagine we have a linear system such $$ Y \approx X\beta $$ where the dependent variables($Y$) and observations matrix ($X$) respectively lie in $ R^n$ and  $R^{n \times p}$ and we are looking for the best solution with minimum $L_2$-norm of $\beta \in R^p$ that minimizes the residuals.

I know that an Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) minimizes the residuals such that it becomes orthogonal to the range of the X.

Now consider this: we break the observation matrix into two matrices $X_k, X_{k'}$ where $X_k$ contains the first $k$ columns of $X$ and similarly $X_{k'}$ the remaining $p-k=:k'$ columns. We do two OLS as follows:

1. finding $\beta_k \in R^k$ such that $||Y-X_k\beta_k||^2$$ is minimized.
2. finding $\beta_{k'} \in R^{k'}$  such that $||(Y-X_k \beta_k) - X_{k'}\beta_{k'}||^2$ is minimized.

The intuition behind this procedure is that by confining $\beta$ to be orthogonal to the range of $k$ features one can capture all the variation of $Y$ over that subspace. Therefore, another OLS using the subtration of the dependent variable and the prediction of smaller sized regression as the new dependent variable should explain fully all the variations of the dependent variable.

I did an experiment by a few lines of code and realized the predicting power (in terms of the RMSE) is not the same and my proposed procedure in by some order of magnitude less accurate. However, I wanted to know if there's a way to prove it algebraically.

---

**PS**: The problem statement is updated dramatically!

Comment: Let $V_k,V_{k'}$ be the column spaces defined by $X_k,X_{k'}$, and $P(V)$ denote the orthogonal projection operator onto a subspace $V$. Your first OLS gives you $P(V_k)Y$, the second gives you $P(V_{k'})P(V_k^\perp)Y$. Their sum is equal to $P(V_k\oplus V_{k'})Y$ if $V_k,V_{k'}$ are orthogonal subspaces, but not in general otherwise.

Comment: @Rahul Fair enough! This deserves to be the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized in fact there's a general theorem that answers exactly my question. The wiki page of [Frisch–Waugh–Lovell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisch%E2%80%93Waugh%E2%80%93Lovell_theorem) concisely explains this.

`@Rahul`'s comment is correct. However, it's a special case. I think the matrix $M_{X_k}$ (or $M_{X_1}$ via wiki's notation) is responsible to map all the remaining regressors to the orthogonal subspace of $V_k$ and therefore, is a more general solution treatment in the sense that after partitioning the regressors, one in general obtains the same weights as the non-partitioned system only if he/she multiplies the RHS with $M_{X_k}$.